# Meaning of "same underlying topological space"

Tags: algebraic-geometry

In this example say I have two schemes, $Z\subseteq X$ where $Z$ is a closed subscheme of $X$. What does it mean to say that $Z$ and $X$ have the same underlying topology? Does it mean that $Z$ and $X$ are homeomorphic as topological space?

thanks!

Comment: Can you give the quotation in full?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a forgetful functor $F: \mathbf{Sch} \to \mathbf{Top}$. To say that $Z$ and $X$ "have the same underlying topological space" means that the closed immersion $Z \to X$ becomes an isomorphism in $\mathbf{Top}$, when you apply $F$ to it.

This happens if and only if the sheaf of ideals defining $Z$ is nilpotent (in the sense that all of its sections are locally nilpotent).

(Remark: for a closed subscheme, it makes no sense to write $Z\subseteq X$. A closed subscheme is not determined by the set of its points in $X$.)